# No me carga slider en Next.js

Tags: reactjs

Trabajando Next.js me figura el siguiente error cuando quiero implementar un slider

```
window is not defined ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at eval (webpack:///./~/style-loader/addStyles.js?:19:3)
    at eval (webpack:///./~/style-loader/addStyles.js?:9:47)
    at module.exports (webpack:///./~/style-loader/addStyles.js?:47:68)
    at eval (webpack:///./~/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css?:12:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/luismorales/Desktop/cotiza-front-accidentes-nyj/node_modules/react-owl-carousel/lib/OwlCarousel.js:147:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/luismorales/Desktop/cotiza-front-accidentes-nyj/node_modules/react-owl-carousel/lib/OwlCarousel.js:30:30)
    at Object.eval (webpack:///./components/OwlCarousel.jsx?:6:104)
    at eval (webpack:///./components/OwlCarousel.jsx?:284:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/luismorales/Desktop/cotiza-front-accidentes-nyj/node_modules/react-owl-carousel/lib/OwlCarousel.js:166:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/luismorales/Desktop/cotiza-front-accidentes-nyj/node_modules/react-owl-carousel/lib/OwlCarousel.js:30:30)
    at /Users/luismorales/Desktop/cotiza-front-accidentes-nyj/node_modules/react-owl-carousel/lib/OwlCarousel.js:76:18
    at /Users/luismorales/Desktop/cotiza-front-accidentes-nyj/node_modules/react-owl-carousel/lib/OwlCarousel.js:79:10
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (/Users/luismorales/Desktop/cotiza-front-accidentes-nyj/node_modules/react-owl-carousel/lib/OwlCarousel.js:3:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/luismorales/Desktop/cotiza-front-accidentes-nyj/node_modules/react-owl-carousel/lib/OwlCarousel.js:10:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Es un error conocido, desde el FAQ de github de Next.js recomiendan hacer lo siguiente: 
Agrega la siguiente validación

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { require('the-lib'); }
```

Puedes ampliar desde aca:
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/FAQ